# How to execute biber?

Tags: biber

[image]

I have installed the texlive 2017, and found out that it contains biber. So I clicked the biber icon, but all I can get is a black screen that disappears in like one second. What is wrong with it? How can I execute the program? Could anyone please help me?

Comment: You can start Biber from the Windows Command Prompt or using your editor. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations%7C for a list of instructions for different editors.

Comment: You can read up about the role of Biber in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864. Biber is a command line tool just like LaTeX itself.